# How Java application connect to wcf https web service with NTLM authentication?

Tags: java, web-services, wcf, ntlmv2

We have a wcf web service, which is deployed to IIS7, and it opens Ntlm authentication, following is config for wcf web service.

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TransportSecurity">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

We also have a Java application, and it need to connect to above web service. We use Axis to generate web service proxy, but we find that the java application can't be authenticated by the service side. I searched a lot in internet, and find that there are some 3rd party libraries(e.g. ntlmv2-auth and Jespa) support Ntlm v2.

We tried to use basic authentication and can connect to the web service successfully, but we still want to use Ntlm authentication.

Is there any built-in libraries created by Java/Sun/Oracle to support nltm v2 except 3rd party libraries?
Can someone compare ntlmv2-auth with Jespa so I can evaluate which one is suitable in my situation?

Answer (score 0):

The Jespa library is good for this type of problem. If you can get your code to use the jespa.http.HttpUrlConnection class for requests, it will do NTLMv2 *properly*.

Comment: Can you add more details?